# What is "--snip--' in python?

Tags: python

In "Automate the boring stuff", there is a strange part that I can not find the answer anywhere either in the book or on the internet, it 's `--snip--` (line 23)
the following code is cited from the book:

[image: here is a picture of my code, --snip-- is at line 23]

It is not a complete code but could you please explain for me what `--snip--` (line 23) does here?

Comment: Can you please add the code you are asking about to the question?

Comment: It's Al's (the author's) way of saying `### code omitted for brevity ###`.

Comment: `--snip--` means nothing. The author has probably used this to indicate that something not immediately relevant to the lesson has been removed. It's like `…`.

Comment: Most probably it is used as  _*I removed some code that is not important*_ - like the sound a scissor makes if you --snip-- something from some other thing.

Answer (score 7):

Most probably it is used as  *I removed some code that is not important* - like the sound a scissor makes if you **--snip--** something from some other thing.

Example usage:

```
for i in range(200):
    print(i)
```

Output:

```
1
2
--snipp--
199
200
```

---

It is similar to [**plonk**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plonk_(Usenet)) - the sound something makes if you put it into the trashbin.

From wikipedia:

- [Onomatopœia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Onomatopoeia):

  > is the process of creating a word that phonetically imitates, resembles, or suggests the sound that it describes. As such words are uncountable nouns, onomatopoeia refers to the property of such words. Common occurrences of words of the onomatopoeia process include animal noises such as *"oink"*, *"miaow"* (or *"meow"*), *"roar"* and *"chirp"*. 
  >   Onomatopoeia can differ between languages: [...] hence the sound of a clock may be expressed as *tick tock* in English, *tictac* in Spanish, *dī dā* in Mandarin, *katchin katchin* in Japanese, or *tik-tik* in Hindi.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I totaly got it.

Answer (score 1):

--snip-- is just a way of explaining things. It's nothing serious. For example, if I have to explain to you an output that is

1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20

, instead of writing this or even bigger values on multiple pages in the book I will save my 2 cents and instead write:

1
2
3
--snip--
19
20

Above makes the point which the writer intended to make, and is also concise and easy to the eyes. Same with the piece of any large code or for that matter anything. Its just a techy or Pythonista way of representing a big chunk of something in a more easy way to the viewer.