# python crash course chapter 9 problem with class

Tags: python

the author wrote that :[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nK8P9.png)

and I make the same :

```
class Dog():
    --snip--
my_dog = Dog('willie', 6)
my_dog.sit()
my_dog.roll_over()
```

but I got the wrong result :

```
    --snip--
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

can anyone explain why that happened?

Comment: That's not Python code, you are not supposed to copy `--snip--` into your own code. It just means "*there are other codes here, but it's not shown here*"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is "--snip--' in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55443046/2745495)

Answer (score 0):

The first two lines are not necessary, they are comment. Don't include them in your code. The author should have defined the class before that.

Answer (score 0):

`--snip--` isn't python. It probably just means to put in the code there. If you want have the class work try:

```
class Dog():
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    def sit(self):
        do something here, can't figure out since there isn't any expected output.
    def roll_over(self):
        do something here, can't figure out since there isn't any expected output.
my_dog = Dog('willie', 6)
my_dog.sit()
my_dog.roll_over()
```

*Note: I don't know what the `sit` and `roll_over` functions are supposed to do. You have to implement it yourself.*